# Getting Import error when tried to install pip through command prompt

Tags: python, pip

I have saved the code for pip as `pip.py`. And tried to install pip through command prompt using below command.
Getting Below error while executing pip.py:

> ImportError: cannot import name cache_from_source

```
python pip.py
```

Comment: Error i am getting:

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: It might help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797365/pip3-version-importerror