# Error using pip to add new libraries in a new environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtual-environment

I have currently three python versions in my pc, each one of them in a different virtual environment. When I try to add a new library in the first or second environment there is no problem, but now I need to use Python version 3.3 (generally I use 3.5 and 3.7) and I created a new environment, and when I use pip to install anything I get the following warning.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Alonso\Anaconda3\envs\py33\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.compat import WINDOWS
  File "c:\users\alonso\anaconda3\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\compat.py", line 54, in <module>
    from importlib.util import cache_from_source
ImportError: cannot import name cache_from_source
```

what is happening?

Comment: No idea, but it may help if you update your question with folder structure and exact commands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip3 --version ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797365/pip3-version-importerror)

Comment: `py33`, really?